# How to write text with double quotes into Yocto local.conf

Tags: bash, docker, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to run bitbake build in Docker. But I also want to add some changes to `conf/local.conf`:

```
docker exec -u jenkins -i yocto /bin/bash -c """...
                                             echo 'DL_DIR = "/home/jenkins/dependencies"' >> /home/jenkins/build/conf/local.conf
                                             echo 'BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS = "1"' >> /home/jenkins/build/conf/local.conf &&
                                             bitbake image"""
```

Build fails with error:

```
ERROR: ParseError at /home/jenkins/build/conf/local.conf:7: unparsed line: 'DL_DIR = /home/jenkins/dependencies'
```

The passed folder path appears without double-quotes. The same if to execute `cat /home/jenkins/build/conf/local.conf`:

```
MACHINE = "qemux86-64"

require conf/variant/common/local.conf
require conf/machine/qemux86-64-extra.conf

VARIANT = "qemux86-64"
DL_DIR = /home/jenkins/dependencies
BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS = 1
```

I also tried like this

```
echo DL_DIR = "\"/home/jenkins/dependencies"\"
```

with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, seem to work with this syntax

```
echo 'DL_DIR = \"/home/jenkins/dependencies\"'
```

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. Kudos for continuing to plug away at your problem!